# Can I use this neutral wire running through the switch box for my smart switch?

Tags: electrical, wiring, multiway-switch, smart-switch

I'm replacing a light switch with a smart switch that requires a neutral wire.  When I removed the existing light switch, I noticed there is a white wire running through the box.  Assuming this is the neutral wire, can I cut that, splice another wire in, cap it, and use for my smart switch?

There is a GFCI switch about 6 inches away.  Could that white wire be going to the GFCI switch?  If so, can I still use it?

Here's a picture of it.  The white wire is in the box.  Can I use that wire if it is indeed the neutral?

[image]

Close up images of inside of box:

[image: inside 1]
[image: inside 2]
[image: inside 3]

Comment: Can you get us photos that show the inside of the box more clearly please?

Comment: Thank you for the response, @ThreePhaseEel.  Additional images added.

Answer (score 1):

Although we can’t see the GFCI it may be the same circuit I would pull the GFCI out and make sure the hot and neutral are for the same circuit.

it looks like you must have conduit make sure to remove the insulator that holds the screw on the switch so the body of the switch has a good ground.